# Tensorflow: Variable Reuse for tf.map_fn

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I created a function `func` that contains some variables. Now, I want to use this function standalone and also through `tf.map_fn` function and I want to keep the same set of variables for both the cases. But, apparently `tf.map_fn` function appends the current variable scope with `map` and hence the variable scope of standalone case can no longer matches the case with `tf.map_fn`. So, the following code throws an error as variable `mul1/map/weights` does not exist before calling it with `reuse=True`.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    D = 5
    batch_size = 1
    def func(x):
        W = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1), shape=[D,1], dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True, name="weights")
        y = tf.matmul(x, W)
        return y

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 5])
    x_cat = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, batch_size, 5])
    with tf.variable_scope("mul1") as mul1_scope:
        y_sum = func(x)
    with tf.variable_scope(mul1_scope, reuse=True):
        cost = tf.map_fn(lambda x: func(x), x_cat)
```

Here I want to run gradient update only on the variables under `mul1/map` scope. So, I can probably use `tf.assign` after every update to change the variables under `mul1` scope (which is used only for the feedforward step). But that's a rather painful way to do variable sharing. So, I was wondering if there is any better way to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated !